# Passing session cookies established in Scrapy to Splash to utilize in scraping js page

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, scrapy-splash

First let me say that I'm a novice at Scrapy!

I have a website that requires a login prior to being able to scrape any data with Scrapy.  The data that I will be scraping is generated by JavaScript once logged in.

I have successfully been able to login using Scrapy.  My question is now that I have logged in and have the necessary cookies to continue making requests of the website how do I transfer those cookies to Splash when envoking a SplashRequest on the report page that I want to scrape with Scrapy?  The documentation that I've read is difficult for me to understand and seems way too generic.  I've looked for examples but have come up blank.

Is my thought process wrong that I should log in with Scrapy then pass the cookies to Splash or should I just be doing this all through Splash?  If so, how do I pass username and password variables in Splash?

Here is my Scrapy code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
     login_url = 'https://example.com/'
     name = 'reports'
     start_urls = [
     login_url
         ]

def parse(self, response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
        'username': 'XXXXXX',
        'password': 'YYYYYY'
    },callback = self.start_requests)

def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://example.com/reports'

    yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.start_scraping)

def start_scraping(self, response):
    labels = response.css('label::text').extract()
    yield {'labeltext': labels}
```

This is simplified for the moment just to return random labels so that I know I'm logged in and Scrapy is seeing the report.  What is happening is it is logging on but of course once I envoke Splash to render the javaScript report Splash is being redirected to login rather than going to the example.com/reports website.  Any help or points in the right direction would be MUCH appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as usual, after spending hours searching and several more experimenting I found the answer and am now behind the login scraping data using Scrapy from a JS created table.  Also as usual I was over complicating things.

Below is my code that is based on the above and simplistically logs in using Splash and then starts scraping.

This utilizes the tool SplashFormRequest rather than Scrapy's FormRequest to login using Splash.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashFormRequest
from ..items import UnanetTestItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    login_url = 'https://example.com'
    name = 'Example'
    start_urls = [
    login_url
        ]

def parse(self, response):
    return SplashFormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'password'
        },
        callback = self.start_scraping)

def start_scraping(self, response):
#whatever you want to do from here.
```